# Check if null attribute present in Optional and return String Java Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream, option-type

I have the following

```
class Person
  private String firstName;
  private String familyName;

  // Setters and Getters
```

And I have the following method

```
public String getFullName(Optional<Person> persons) {
  return persons
           .map(person -> (person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getFamilyName())).orElse("Invalid");
}
```

I just want to check if either first or last name is `null`, display `"Invalid"` for that person. I was thinking to add a method for validation but I am sure there is an easier way I cannot think about.

Comment: Passing `Optional` as a parameter is not a good idea. instead, having `Optional<String>` for the method would be better. something like this: `Optional<String> getFullName(Person person) {
        if (person.getFamilyName() == null && person.getFirstName() == null) return Optional.empty();
        return Optional.of(person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getFamilyName());
    }`

Comment: @HadiJ Good point. Also thought about that after answering the question. The developers cannot get used to the original purpose of `Optional`, being a safe way to **return** a nullable value. Having `Optional` as a method parameter is kinda violating this principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking to [`Optional::filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-), before the map:

```
return persons
        .filter(person -> person.getFamilyName() != null && person.getFirstName() != null)
        .map(person -> person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getFamilyName())
        .orElse("Invalid");
```

Which mean, if the family and first names are not null then create your concatination, otherwise return an Invalid message, or you can even throw an exception by using `orElseThrow`

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter for that:

```
public String getFullName(Optional<Person> persons) {
  return persons
           .filter(person -> Objects.nonNull(person.getFirstName()) && Objects.nonNull(person.getFamilyName()))
           .map(person -> (person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getFamilyName())).orElse("Invalid");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another functional approach.

First create a predicate builder method for required field validation:

```
public static <T, F> Predicate<T> hasRequiredValue(Function<T, F> fieldGetter) {
    return fieldGetter.andThen(Objects::nonNull)::apply;
}
```

And modify the `getFullName` a little bit:

```
public Optional<String> getFullName(Person person) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(person)
                   .filter(hasRequiredValue(Person::getFamilyName))
                   .filter(hasRequiredValue(Person::getFirstName))
                   .map(p -> p.getFirstName() + " " + p.getFamilyName());
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
Person person = ...
String fullName = getFullName(person).orElse("Invalid");
```